# Can you trap environment settings?

Tags: t-sql, variables, session-variables

Remember FoxPro ….

Can you trap a system variable before setting?

Something like

```
DECLARE sysNoCount 
@sysNoCount = SET('NOCOUNT')
SET NOCOUNT ON
--- process
SET NOCOUNT @sysNoCount
```

Comment: Ahhh... FoxPro.  My first true love.

Answer (score 1):

See `SELECT @@Options` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/options-transact-sql

Specifically for `NOCOUNT`:

`SET @sysNoCount = @@Options & 512;`